# Why do we put deltaTime as an argument in render() LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, rendering, timestep

I know that `deltaTime` is the time the last frame took to be rendered. However, I have no idea why we have to put it inside the parameter of the render method. I also don't know how the render method takes use of the `deltaTime`.

Comment: It's hard to speculate without hard facts. Perhaps the statement "deltaTime is the time the last frame took to be rendered .. put it inside the parameter of the render method" is not correct after all?

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to compensate for jitter in rendering using gpu-side prediction. For example you have an object moving at a constant speed.

You add the speed to the uniforms used when rendering the object and the delta time. Then in the vertex shader you can do `worldPos = worldPos + speed * deltaTime` before doing the camera and perspective transforms (or fold it into the transformation matrix).

Example:

```
absolute    deltaTime   render      (calculated)
time        (last frame)position
0           0           (w+0)+0     0
10          10          (w+10)+10   20
20          10          (w+20)+10   30
110         90          (w+110)+90  200
120         10          (w+120)+10  130
130         10          (w+130)+10  140
140         10          (w+140)+10  150
200         60          (w+200)+60  270
210         10          (w+210)+10  220
220         10          (w+220)+10  230
230         10          (w+230)+10  240
```

Comment: Could you clarify, how is "the time the *last frame* took to be rendered" supposed to compensate jitter? E.g. previous frame lagged and took 50ms instead of 16ms.

Comment: @Kromster that's the second paragraph

Comment: Sorry, is it true to assume that `worldPos` changes after each frame?

Comment: @Kromster yeah, based on the last render or deltatime can get accumulated from the last update.

Comment: I have written in notepad both options - jitter does not seem to be compesated that way. In fact, it seems to become even worse - frame after the last laggy one jumps ahead and then next one jumps back. Could you please provide an example of how it supposed to work in a table with 5-8 frames timings?

Comment: I have added template table. Please fill it as you intend, or rollback/delete if needed. *Just trying to sort the issue out.*

Comment: So basically, if there are various devices that differ in their fps, the speed of the objects in the game will be different in each devices, which is unfair for the users. So the deltatime in the render () makes it possible for the speed of objects to be constant throughout all the different devices, am I right?

Comment: @user97478 No. Game has to be the same on all devices, this is why it's split into game logic and disconnected from rendering. Game logic typically runs at static rate (e.g. 10 updates per second in RTS). Render is just displays whatever it has, with render interpolation (deltas) to smooth transitions.

Answer (score 2):

The `delta` variable can be used for many things. Mainly it is used to make your game framerate independent. Framerate independent means that your game behaves the same no matter how many frames per second your game is running at.

For example; let's say you want your player to move at 600 units per second. Since we know our game updates at 60 FPS we calculate that we should move at `600 / 60 = 10` units per update. So we write this code:

```
public void render() {
    position += 10; // Move 10 units per update = 600 units per second.
}
```

Fantastic, our player is now moving at 600 units per second, just like we wanted! [But wait, there's more!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_RLYSaPvak) Let's say we encounter some lag and our game drops down to 40 FPS. Now our code will move us `10 * 40 = 400` units per second! Yikes, not good!

But what if we instead took *actual time* elapsed into account and used this to calculate our speed instead? The code would change to something like this:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    position += 600 * delta; // 600 units per >second<.
}
```

Now, since speed is calculated in *"per second"* instead of *"per update"* we will always move at a constant speed no matter the framerate! Hurrah!

Comment: Sure, but why is it there [when `Gdx.graphics.deltaTime` is a thing](https://javadoc.io/static/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/1.2.0/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getDeltaTime())? Seems pretty redundant to have both, especially when the delta argument doesn't appear in the ApplicationAdapter render function

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine If you are in some scope where you do not have access to the delta time parameter you can use the global `Gdx.graphics.deltaTime` to access the delta. They are always the same value :) In general passing the delta as an argument is better because it allows for easier testing of your code, e.g. when testing you can put delta as `1.0f` to simulate a 1 second timestep (super laggy). You can't do that with `Gdx.graphics.deltaTime`.